# How do I create a PHP project in IntelliJ 13?

Tags: php, intellij-idea

Seems simple enough, but when I pick PHP the only option is "Composer Project" and if I don't enter something for "Package", I get "No package selected".

Could someone explain this like I'm 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the ["Static Web"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/new-project-main-settings.html#d228452e1210) project kind?

> Web modules are used for developing Web applications using technologies such as HTML/CSS, JavaScript, PHP and so on. They do not support developing Java applications.

It will generate an empty project where you can structure your project as you wish.